# Checking that fileupload is successfull in blueimp jquery fileupload plugin

Tags: php, file-upload, blueimp

I want to update a database table on the successful file upload using *blueimp pluggin*

Say when my update is complete, I want to run this query

```
mysql_query("
           UPDATE td_post 
           SET post_name='$p_name'
               ,post_image='$img_url' 
           WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['logged_user']."'"
           );
```

But I can't find the place where I should check the return result and then update the query...

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadClass.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$path = "your/upload/path/filename";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0],$path)){
      //run your query here
}
```